# HTTP Return Code for "Invalid" Body

Tags: rest, http

Let's say I have a REST POST end-point: `www.foo.com/validate/X` where X represents a number.

My server-side pseudocode looks like this:

```
validateId(id, jsonObj) { 

  if ( isValid(jsonObj) { return 200/OK }
  else { return ??? }
}
```

What's the right HTTP return code here for the `else` case? Basically I want to indicate to the client that its `jsonObj` is not valid.

Comment: 400 Bad Request or 422 Unprocessable Entity http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP-Statuscode

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about using WebDAV codes, `422 Unprocessable Entity` is the most adequate, otherwise, use `400 Bad Request`.

Answer (score 1):

Usually for validating an input we have to use  400 (Bad Request) and your validation text( if the input wrong). You can read about in RESTful Web Services or other REST books.